# Unable to iterate Jobject when having single value

Tags: c#, foreach, jobjectformatter

I am using for each to iterate and get values of a json object in my solution.
Let me give example of the json.

```
 [
  {
    "@Seq": "1",
    "#text": "123456789"
  },
  {
    "@Seq": "2",
    "#text": "abc"
  },
  {
    "@Seq": "3",
    "#text": "xyz"
  }
]
```

It works well for multiple sequences until we have only one seq in the json.
example:

```
{{
  "@Seq": "1",
  "#text": "123456789"
}}
```

Coming to Code:

```
     foreach (var installinst in atpmessage["AUTOPILOTMessage"]["AUTOPILOTBody"]["OrderHeader"]["InstallationInstructions"]["InstallationInstruction"])
  {

                       responseISGEMEA.data.install_instruct =installinst["#text"].ToString();

   }
```

The installinst in the loop gives me just the Seq. Not the text.

```
{"@Seq": "1"}
```

how do I make it work with single and multiple sequences.

Comment: Why won't you deserialize your json?

Comment: This is just a section of a really big json which doesn’t have specific items in it. I tried doing it but for some complex json, I was not able to serialize it